# Is Heap considered an Abstract Data Type?

Tags: data-structures, heap, priority-queue, abstract-data-type

I'm taking Data-Structure course and got a little confused about what is considered to be an ADT (Abstract Data Type) and what isn't (and if it isn't an ADT then it must be the implementation?).

Specifically, I'm talking about Heap.

I've read in Wikipedia that " heap is a specialized tree-based data structure" does that mean it is an ADT? if so, then I can't understand the following line, also from Wikipedia "The heap is one maximally efficient implementation of an abstract data type called a priority queue".

I mean, can Heap be an ADT and also be an implementation of some other ADT (in this case an implementation of priority queue? I understand the concept of ADT and in the context of Binary Heap I understand that it can be implemented using array where `arr[i]` is the parent of `arr[2i]` and `arr[2i + 1]` 
I'm just confused about whether a Heap can be in one hand an ADT which implemented using array and on the other hand a data-structure that implements other ADT.

Would like to get some clarifications about this.

Comment: It seems like this question isn't about programming but rather about terminology for your classwork. You might find better luck on http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @DanRoche you are right that it isn't about programming but more about the programming theory background.. thought I can ask it here.. I will check where you said. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a theoretical question that probably belongs on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Heap is not an ADT. It is a Data Structure.**

---

The obligatory Wikipedia quote:

> *In computer science, an abstract data type (ADT) is a mathematical
> model for data types where a data type is defined by its behavior
> (semantics) from the point of view of a user of the data, specifically
> in terms of possible values, possible operations on data of this type,
> and the behavior of these operations. This contrasts with data
> structures, which are concrete representations of data, and are the
> point of view of an implementer, not a user.*

---

**Bonus content inspired from Code Complete - 2 by Steve McConnell.**

*Data Structures are low-level implementation domain items, in contrast with ADTs which work in the problem domain. ADTs let you manipulate real-world entities rather than low-level, implementation entities. Instead of inserting a node into a linked-list or adding an item to a heap, you can add a cell to a spreadsheet, a new type of window to window types, or another passenger to a train simulation.*

- *You can clearly see that heap has defined semantics like insert(), heapify(), peek(), getTop() etc. - listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Operations) in detail. Hence it is a data structure.*
- *However, if you simulate a game of Tetris where adding a new block will simply go and sit on top of wherever it falls, this Tetris game's UI will actually be an ADT.*

Comment: thank you for your answer , it's helpful but I'm not sure I'm agree with:

 "You can clearly see that heap has defined semantics - push(), peek(), getTop(). Hence it is a data structure."

push() , peek() getTop() are the main operations of stack which is actually an ADT and not of a heap.
Heap main operations are Create , Insert , Delete , getMax(/Min).

Comment: @Noam: Updated my answer. While the semantics that I wrote were correct for heap, the were misguiding in the fact that they were specific semantics for Stacks too. The new answer should be unambiguous.

Comment: But it's still questionable: if a Heap is a data structure, which is the ADT it implements then? because, for every data structure, according to the definition, there should be an ADT which that data structure implements.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: DSes are just ways to arrange data. ADTs relate to the problem you are solving. There is no such rule that “Every data structure has to have a ADT”. Can you provide me any link for the definition you are stating here? I read the [Wikipedia page of DS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) and there is no such statement. (1/2)

Comment: From the first para of Usage section of the above linked page - "Data structures serve as the basis for abstract data types (ADT). The ADT defines the logical form of the data type. The data structure implements the physical form of the data type." (2/2)

Answer (score 5):

I would try to clarify about this confusion other way round. Quoting wikipedia from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue):

> While priority queues are often implemented with heaps, they are
> conceptually distinct from heaps. A priority queue is an abstract
> concept like "a list" or "a map"; just as a list can be implemented
> with a linked list or an array, a priority queue can be implemented
> with a heap or a variety of other methods such as an unordered array.

So, heap is an implementation of an abstract data type(ADT) named Priority Queue. This means that heap is a Data Structure. Priority Queue ADT can be implemented in many other ways listed below but is not limited to:

- Unordered Array
- Unordered List
- Ordered Array
- Ordered List
- Binary Search Tree (BST)
- Balanced Binary Search Tree (AVL-tree)
- Binary heap (asked by OP)

Comparing the time efficiency of heap implementation for main operations in Priority Queue ADT with other possible implementations:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Implementation | Insertion   | Deletion(DeleteMax/DeleteMin)|Find Max/Min
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Unordered Array| 1           | n                            | n
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Unordered List | 1           | n                            | n
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Ordered Array  | n           | 1                            | 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Ordered List   | n           | 1                            | 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| BST            | logn (avg.) | logn (avg.)                  | logn (avg.)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Balanced BST   | log n       | log n                        | log n
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Binary Heaps   | log n       | log n                        | 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Heap is not considered an abstract data type.

Heap is a specialized tree-based data structure that is an implementation of the abstract data type called Priority Queue.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

Comment: thank you for your answer but it isn't so helpful. As I mentioned in my post I've read what wikipedia has to say about heap and I simply confused because if heap isn't adt how come that it has different implementations (for example, linked list and array implementations) I thought that once there are several different implementation to a data type that makes it abstract.

Comment: @Noam: Then I don't have an answer for you. Most likely you'll get better answers on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Noam: Having different implementations does not make a DS an ADT. It is common for DSes to have different backing DSes and therefore different performance numbers for same operation. Ex. HashSets can be both array backed as well as tree backed. Array backed ones are generally called HashSets while tree backed are called TreeSets. TreeSets are by a specialized implementation of and therefore by default, are HashSets. They do not become ADTs just because they have been implemented differently. The fact that they have specified semantics makes them a DS. ADTs make no promise on semantics.

Answer (score 1):

I am showing you the complete line from wikipedia whereas you quoted just the part of line which confused you.maybe you have better understood it if you just got to next part of line.

> The heap is one maximally efficient implementation of an abstract data type called a priority queue, and in fact priority queues are often referred to as "heaps", regardless of how they may be implemented. A common implementation of a heap is the binary heap, in which the tree is a binary tree

here it says that

> in fact priority queues are often referred to as "heaps", regardless of how they may be implemented.

because of the popularity of heap data structure(DS), in implementing priority queues ADT.priority queues ADT are often referred as heap

In the next line of wikipedia quote

> A common implementation of a heap is the binary heap, in which the tree is a binary tree

Here first heap means priority queue and binary heap means in short heap means data structure.

hence forth when you see heap (in context of ADT) it actually means priority queue ADT and heap is a implementation of it.hence heap is a DS.

also where you quotes this:

> " heap is a specialized tree-based data structure"

it simply means it is a DS not ADT.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Java Software Structures,International Edition [John Lewis, Joseph Chase]**

> An abstract data type (ADT) is a data type whose values and operations
>   are not inherently defined within a programming language. It is
>   abstract only in that the details of its implementation must be
>   defined and should be hidden from the user. A collection, therefore,
>   is an abstract data type.

**2) Algorithms, 4th Edition by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne**

> Using abstract data types You do not need to know how a data type is implemented in order to be able to use it.

So if you only are designing a behaviour like this:

**3) Wikipead heap operations:**

```
Basic

    find-max (or find-min): find a maximum item of a max-heap, or a minimum item of a min-heap, respectively (a.k.a. peek)
    insert: adding a new key to the heap (a.k.a., push[4])
    extract-max (or extract-min): returns the node of maximum value from a max heap [or minimum value from a min heap] after removing it from the heap (a.k.a., pop[5])
    delete-max (or delete-min): removing the root node of a max heap (or min heap), respectively
    replace: pop root and push a new key. More efficient than pop followed by push, since only need to balance once, not twice, and appropriate for fixed-size heaps.[6]

Creation

    create-heap: create an empty heap
    heapify: create a heap out of given array of elements
    merge (union): joining two heaps to form a valid new heap containing all the elements of both, preserving the original heaps.
    meld: joining two heaps to form a valid new heap containing all the elements of both, destroying the original heaps.

Inspection

    size: return the number of items in the heap.
    is-empty: return true if the heap is empty, false otherwise.

Internal

    increase-key or decrease-key: updating a key within a max- or min-heap, respectively
    delete: delete an arbitrary node (followed by moving last node and sifting to maintain heap)
    sift-up: move a node up in the tree, as long as needed; used to restore heap condition after insertion. Called "sift" because node moves up the tree until it reaches the correct level, as in a sieve.
    sift-down: move a node down in the tree, similar to sift-up; used to restore heap condition after deletion or replacement.
```

Realy this is only an ADT, and the implementation is the Data Structure, in fact, one of the two books defined the heap as ADT

So, by 1 and 2, indicate that 3 can be a ADT of a heap, because you can implementet the heap with an array and with a pointers for example. and the same for the priority queue, but the time complexity can change

In the **Java Software Structures,International Edition [John Lewis, Joseph Chase]** has the HeapADT

```
public interface HeapADT<T> extends BinaryTreeADT<T>
{
/**
* Adds the specified object to this heap.
*
* @param obj the element to be added to this heap
*/
public void addElement (T obj);
/**
* Removes element with the lowest value from this heap.
*
* @return the element with the lowest value from this heap
*/
public T removeMin();
/**
* Returns a reference to the element with the lowest value in
* this heap.
*
* @return a reference to the element with the lowest value in this heap
*/
public T findMin();
}
```

but in **Algorithms, 4th Edition by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne** has the PriorityQueue as an ADT:

```
public class MaxPQ< Key extends Comparable<Key>> 
MaxPQ() create a priority 
queueMaxPQ(int max) create a priority queue of initial capacity max 
MaxPQ(Key[] a) create a priority queue from the keys in a[]
void  insert(Key v) insert a key into the priority queueKey  
max() return the largest keyKey  
delMax() return and remove the largest key  
boolean isEmpty() is the priority queue empty?
int  size() number of keys in the priority queue
```

And as a DS: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/MaxPQ.java.html

And I think that they only say this:

> The  **binary heap is a data structure** that can efficiently support the 
>   basic  priority-queue  operations.  In  a  binary  heap,  the  keys

Because they are talk about the implementation:

> are  **stored  in  an  array** such that each key is guaranteed to be
>   larger than (or equal to) the keys at two other specific positions.

Another example could be say, about List, List  could be an adt and static array and dinamic array are the data structures to implement a List, but another authors define the ADT to, because is the expected behaviour.

You can chek this arrays adt in this another book: **DATA STRUCTURES IN C++ by N. S. KUTTI, P. Y. PADHYE** (you can check [here](http://ttps://books.google.es/books?id=Rl2O3VM89roC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=static%20array%20adt&source=bl&ots=tGyqmn4TVz&sig=ACfU3U0l5ICOLT86gmspMMb4_eFTlfUbxQ&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKopTcmZTkAhVIExoKHb2QA_QQ6AEwF3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=static%20array%20adt&f=false))

So finnaly, if you are defining the behaviour of something I would say that is a ADT, and if you are doing the implementation I would say that is a DS.

**Edit:**

Another contradiction between books

**Data Structures & Algorithms in Java Robert Lafore**

> A priority queue is a more specialized data structure